# Comment traduire « curiosity killed the cat » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, proverbes

Je ne connais pas d'équivalent en français.  Excepté « la curiosité est un vilain défaut ».

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rien de mieux à proposer que "la curiosité est un vilain défaut", qui semble être [la traduction acceptée](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/curiosity_killed_the_cat).

A lire aussi: [une liste de citations sur le sujet](http://www.evene.fr/citations/mot.php?mot=curiosite) qui semble attribuer une citation similaire  à "la curiosité est un vilain défaut" à Ambrose Bierce.

Answer (score 5):

Une expression moins "toute faite" qui traduit assez littéralement : "C'est sa curiosité qui l'a tué"

Comment: euh oui mais ça n'existe pas comme expression

Comment: @Nikko: ah bon? Ce n'est peut être pas une "expression", mais c'est une formule fréquente.

Comment: je veux bien te croire, mais ça sonne très bizarre à mes oreilles

Answer (score 2):

> ***La curiosité malgré tous ses attraits
>
> Coûte souvent bien des regrets***

Charles Perrault, *La Barbe bleue*, 1697.

Answer (score 1):

On peut déduire de cette [page](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/curiosity+killed+the+cat]) qu'il y a dans « Curiosity killed the cat. » quelque chose en moins et quelque chose en plus que dans « La curiosité est un vilain défaut. ». Il manque l'[aspect moral](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=2439916755;r=1;nat=;sol=1;) qu'exprime « vilain » : aucun jugement moral n'est apporté et le jugement que l'on peut déchiffrer sans difficulté est qu'il existe associé à la curiosité un élément de danger. Il ne faut donc en aucun cas faire de « La curiosité est un vilain défaut. » une traduction.

Pour rester fidèle au texte anglais il faut rendre l'adage par des termes qui expriment ce qu'il signifie puis, éventuellement, si l'on juge bon de faire part au lecteur de l'esprit de ce que l'on traduit, d'expliquer dans une note de bas de page que cela est tiré d'un adage anglais.

- Se laisser aller à la curiosité peut être dangereux.
- La curiosité n'est pas toujours sans danger.
- La curiosité peut couter cher.
- Fourrer son nez dans les affaires des autres peut être dangereux.

…

Il y a évidemment l'option de fournir un équivalent français si l'on juge finalement que celui-ci sera un apport à la langue française. C'est selon le [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/La+curiosit%C3%A9+a+tu%C3%A9+le+chat) ce qu'ont déjà fait certaines personnes au moyen d'une traduction littérale (La curiosité a tué le chat.).  Au vu de la curiosité naturelle du chat la traduction littérale semble la meilleure solution.

Answer (score 0):

La curiosité n’est pas forcément un vilain défaut.  La traduction littérale est préférable pour les raisons données.

Comment: Comme on a déjà cette réponse, c'est plutôt une commentaire.  Voici le [tour] et le [help] pour faciliter les réponses.